# optimized way of passing a form in all view functions django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a `form` which is needed in all the view functions of my **django** project.

I have a `common template` for printing the form but for this I have to pass the form from all my view functions.

I have about **8 apps**. To include the form in all my view functions. Plus the form can be bound or blank depending on a session value.

If I write the lines for including the form I have to write 5 lines. So I have to write those 5 lines to all my view functions. Any way to do this in a better way?

`forms.py`

```
    class LanguageSelectForm(forms.Form):
        language = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label='--Select A Language--', queryset=Language.objects.all(),
                                  widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

in `views.py`

```
    form = LanguageSelectForm
        if 'language_id' in request.session:
            form_data = dict()
            form_data['language'] = request.session['language_id']
            form = LanguageSelectForm(form_data)
```

these are the 5 lines i had to put on all of my view functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can want to use this form in django templates(every) you must write context processors:
Please read this links:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/template/context_processors/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Comment: Could you include the relevant parts so future developers can learn from your answer?

Answer (score 2):

As `@Mubariz Feyziyev` mentioned, you can use `context processors` to render your form in each template. This is one way to this. Additionally,

If you are OK with `not` using django forms:

- Create your form with pure html on client side,
- Set its `action` value to a particular url like `/api/handle-my-nice-form`,
- Create a view that handles this form's request and connect it to `url` record (`/api/handle-my-nice-form/`)

If you are new to `Django`, You should use built-in forms. But as your app grows and gets complicated or if you decided to use a library like `React` or `Angular`; it might be better building `an api based system` to handle this kind of stuff.